# Conditional Variance of $Z_i|\sum_i\beta_iZ_i$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, variance, conditional-expectation, conditional-variance

Let's assume I have $K$ i.i.d. standard normal random variables $Z_1,...,Z_K$. Hence, I know that $V[Z_i] = 1$ and $E[Z_i] = 0$ for all $i\in K$. I am faced with computing the following conditional variance:
$$ V\left[Z_i| \sum_i\beta_iZ_i\right] \quad\; \text{where} \quad\; \sum_i\beta_i^2 = 1$$
where $\beta_i >0$ is just a non-null parameter. Can I show that:

$$ V\left[Z_i| \sum_i\beta_iZ_i\right] = V[Z_i] = 1$$

Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: Because $(Z_i, \sum\beta_iZ_i)$ has a bivariate Normal distribution, all you need to do is compute its parameters and apply either standard regression formulas or [normal conditional variance formulas](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=normal+conditional+distribution).  For insight, consider the case $K=2,$ $i=1,$ and $\beta=(1,0),$ which is tantamount to asking about the variance of $Z_1$ conditional on $Z_1.$

Comment: @Whuber: Thanks a lot for your comment and suggestions ! Regarding your example, I specifically set $\beta_i>0$ for all $i \in K$ to exactly avoid this scenario. Do you think it is possible to prove the relationship I mention in my question analytically ?

Comment: My example is for intuition.  If you're so concerned about strict positivity, consider $\beta=(1-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ for an infinitesimally small positive $\epsilon.$

Comment: @Whuber: Yes, I perfectly understand and thank again for your comment :)

Comment: @Whuber: the key part for me would be to be able to prove that Z_i is independent of the sum of the Z_i. This is a result used in a research paper I am reading. I simplified the example here from the full development. I am a bit confused about "how" this would be possible...

Comment: It's not independent, as you can see by computing the covariance of $Z_i$ with the sum, which equals $\beta_i\ne 0.$  I would like to suggest you would get more out of your post by describing the actual situation rather than a simplification of it.

Comment: @Whuber: Thanks for your suggestion, I have just done so in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4885012/independence-between-z-i

Comment: @Whuber: thanks a lot for all your insights. Indeed, now I better understand what you were saying here. Specifically, that to reach independence between $Z_i$
 and $\sum_iβ_iZ_i$ we would need to impose a condition on $β_i$, as the covariance $Cov[Z_i,\sum_iβ_iZ_i]=β_iV[Z_i]=β_i$